How to kill an unresponsive process programmatically using Rust on Windows?
I have a Windows Rust app that is only allowed to have 1 instance running. It uses a file based lock to make sure only 1 process can be open at a time. Occasionally, the app will become unresponsive and when the user opens it again it will not kill the unresponsive process. If the process is working and a user attempts to open another one, it kills the old process successfully. Is there a way to force kill an unresponsive process?
Here's the implementation:
lazy_static! {
    static ref LOCK_PATH: PathBuf = env::temp_dir().join("tl-lock");
    static ref EXE_NAME: String = {
        let exe_path = env::current_exe().unwrap();
        exe_path
            .file_name()
            .expect("Cannot get EXE name")
            .to_str()
            .expect("Invalid EXE name")
            .to_string()
    };
}


/// Terminate all processes that have the same name
/// This prevents people from having multiple copies open
fn kill_dangling_processes() {
    let exe_name = &*EXE_NAME;
    let sys = System::new_all();
    for (_, process) in sys.processes() {
        if process.name() == exe_name {
            process.kill();
        }
    }
}

/// This function is ran on start
pub fn lock() {
    if LOCK_PATH.exists() {
        kill_dangling_processes();
        return;
    }
    fs::write(LOCK_PATH.clone(), "locked").unwrap();
}



The only thing that kills the unresponsive process is right clicking on it and force killing it in the task bar.

Looking at the documentation for the sysinfo create (https://docs.rs/sysinfo/latest/sysinfo/struct.Process.html), there is another method called kill_with.
I am not familiar with killing processes on Windows, but I assume you will have to find the equivalent of kill -9 on Unix/Linux systems. Process::kill seems to only send kill -2 which will have no effect on an unresponsive process.

This will not work. Windows only supports the Kill signal.

That's a shame. Will, then this answer would still be valid for *nix.
